# Three.js shadow issue

Tags: webgl, three.js, shadow

I have a problem with my Three.js script. I have this scene,

http://jsfiddle.net/Rhtr2/7/

but as soon as I enable shadows (uncomment `spot.castShadow=true;`) it gets to this:

http://prntscr.com/jx7id

I'm not sure where in my code is the problem, but I think it is something obviously.

Btw: Other Three.js examples with shadow work, so it's not a generally problem of my gpu, and there is no console output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your fiddle. Please see the three.js examples for how to add a `renderer` to the DOM correctly.

Also, you need to experiment until you understand how rotations work in three.js.

And you need to set your shadow camera `near` and `far planes` correctly.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhtr2/58/

---

Yikes! Fiddle Version 58! Read the jsfiddle FAQ. You do not need to "update" your fiddle to run it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wf_bitplan_com/poz5Lm0b/12/ has an updated r105 version (with console output for better debugging).